# Azure functions swap functionality is not working after enabling private endpoint for function app linked storage

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-virtual-network

Azure functions swap functionality is not working after enabling private endpoint(with selected networks option) for function app linked storage account(webjobstorage)

Created private endpoint for blob, file and table storage

Below are the additional app settings I am adding

```
{
    "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET",
    "value": "1",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
    "value": "production",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER",
    "value": "168.63.129.16",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL",
    "value": "1",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
```

Referred this article [Secure storage account linked to Function App with private endpoint](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/secure-storage-account-linked-to-function-app-with-private/ba-p/2644772)

From the azure devops I am trying to deploy the code to staging slot first, then later I am swapping it with prod slot. at this step it is failing.

Tried to swap it from the portal that also failed.

I am getting below error

From devops swap task :

```
##[error]Error: Failed to swap App Service 'testmgmt-fa-min-go' slots - 'staging' and 'production'. Error: InternalServerError - There was an unexpected error swapping slots 'staging' and 'production' for site 'testmgmt-fa-min-go(staging)'. Please try to cancel your swap operation. (CODE: 500)
```

From Portal:

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue, determined that it is with storage account network restrictions. i.e., if you allow access from all network to the storage hosting function files, then this swap issue will go away. Now trying to pinpoint exact settings to avoid giving more permission than required.

Comment: @UBK  yes the issue is related to storage account restriction.  My existing setup allows all network in storage and with that setup swap slots works seamlessly , but I want restrict the public access.

Comment: I tried to trace the call with our network suppor team, didn't help. I ended up creating a self-hosted agent (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) for my DevOps repo in an Azure Virtual machine, which is inside the same VNET as the Az function private endpoints. With this I was able to build and release directly to the default slot which has private endpoint restrictions.

Comment: @UBK, 
More details about my end to end setup
Function App setups --
  - vent integrated with  **function-subnet**
 - Access restriction allowed access from  AzureEventGridServiceTag, APIM IP, ,SelfHostAgent Subnet.

Storage Account Setup-
  **Private endpoint** for blob, file, queue, table.
 **selected network** - function and self host subnet
Allow azure trusted Service.

From the release pipeline Azure App Service deploy(deploy code to staging slot) task is working after the deployment swap slot task is failing.

Comment: my guess  is 
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionid}/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/myfunctionapp/slots/staging/slotsswap?api-version=2018-11-01  this API is not able to communicate with the storage account when the selected network is selected.

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by an internal platform component, and I’ll updated this question to notify when the component fix has been fully released. Unfortunately, the ETA for a full roll out is within the next 3 to 4 months.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/8448

Answer (score 1):

The fix is deployed but we had to introduce a new app setting that you should set on your production slot (or the swap slot if you're swapping between two subslots) called WEBSITE_OVERRIDE_STICKY_DIAGNOSTICS_SETTINGS and set it to **0** (zero). I.e.,

WEBSITE_OVERRIDE_STICKY_DIAGNOSTICS_SETTINGS=0

This will allow you to swap the slots when the storage account is network restricted. Here is our [documentation on app settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal). This should not have any impact on your Azure Monitor related diagnostics settings configuration and is related to the legacy Application Log Settings configuration, which was preventing Premium Functions slot swaps from occurring.

Next steps on our side are:

- We will add to our backlog a work item for this setting to defaulted for Premium Functions, so you won't have to add it but currently no ETA for this, so the above is the current final solution.
- We will add the app setting to our App Settings list documentation

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  But After Swap, this setting is getting removed. Is this the actual behavior ? Do you need to set the settings before doing swap?

Comment: Apologies for missing this follow up. To clarify, set it to 0 in the production slot and mark it as a Deployment Slot setting (aka sticky), or add to all slots to make sure that all version settings are also swapped. The documentation update with the description of this app setting is behind a larger PR still under review.

Comment: I did NOT actually restrict my network settings but this suddenly started affecting my Azure Function -- with NO no explanation or reason.  However, adding this Configuration setting did work though it's ridiculous that we have to search this out here and in the GitHub thread (https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/8448) for a brand newly deployed Linux Azure Func.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @UBK, your comment helped me to resolve the same swapping issue in my Azure Private Endpoint Function App.

I tried to reproduce the issue by following the given documentation: [Secure storage account linked to Function App with private endpoint - Microsoft Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/secure-storage-account-linked-to-function-app-with-private/ba-p/2644772)

Solved the swapping issue by allowing access to all networks in the Networking of Storage Account.

Comment: In my case I want storage account to allow access to selected network. An azure trusted services. But swap is not working some how. 
From devops, Azure code deploy task is able to deploy the code.